# Json::Value as private class member

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I'm writing a C++ class for Reading/Writing strings from/to a json file using the jsoncpp lib.
My question is if it's possible to create a Json::Value private member for my class and use this every time I need to read/write instead of creating a new Json::Value inside every function?

If so, how can I initialize it in the constructor and access it inside every function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any special initialization for the `Json::Value`. You can make it a `private` member variable and use it like any other member variable.

Here's an example where I've added support for streaming from/to `istream/ostream` objects and a few member functions to demonstrate access to specific fields:

```
#include "json/json.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class YourClass {
public:
    // two public accessors:
    double getTemp() const { return json_value["Temp"].asDouble(); }
    void setTemp(double value) { json_value["Temp"] = value; }

private:
    Json::Value json_value;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, YourClass& yc) {
        return is >> yc.json_value;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const YourClass& yc) {
        return os << yc.json_value;
    }
};

int main() {
    YourClass yc;

    if(std::ifstream file("some_file.json"); file) {
        file >> yc;      // read file
        std::cout << yc; // print result to screen

        // use public member functions
        std::cout << yc.getTemp() << '\n';
        yc.setTemp(6.12);
        std::cout << yc.getTemp() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Edit: I was asked to explain the `if` statement and it means [`if(` *init-statement* `;` *condition* `)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) (added in C++17) which becomes approximately the same as this:

```
{ // scope of `file`
    std::ifstream file("some_file.json");

    if(file) { // test that `file` is in a good state
        // ... 
    }
} // end of scope of `file`
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense!
My use case is that I want to for example read temperature from a json file containing multipile members. For example it can contain, temp, humidity, wind etc..
So my plan is to create public member functions for reading/writing these values.
For example:
std::string ReadTemp() or void WriteTemp().
Do I get access to specific member using return is >> yc.json_value["Temp"] or similiar?

Comment: @Linus Yes, after you've read the file, you can access the member named `json_value` in all your member functions. Perhaps streaming directly into certain subobjects like `is >> yc.json_value["Temp"]` isn't optimal, but it's possible.

Comment: @Linus I added two accessor functions to demo

Comment: thank you so much! Will try, obviously made it much more complicated in my head

Comment: @Linus You're welcome and happy hacking!

Comment: What does this line really do?
if(std::ifstream file("some_file.json"); file)

I get that we open a stream toward the json file, but don't understand the semicolon after.

Comment: @Linus I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! One last question;
By using the public member functions I can now read/write as printed below:
{
 "Temp" : "15"
}
{
 "Temp" : "22"
}
However, the file is reset back to 15 when the program ends. So I believe I'm not actually overwriting the value?

Comment: @Linus No, exacly. All the changes are only made in memory. If you want to save it, then `if(std::ofstream ofs("file"); ofs) { ofs << yc; }` should do it